# What are the limits of the Plugin Dependencies "Find Unused Dependencies" Feature?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I've been trying to use the "Find Unused Dependencies" option in the eclipse plugin development tools, but for any project of modest complexity I get a heap space error.

For a representative example, see [Osate2-Core](https://github.com/osate/osate2-core), an open source, modest sized collection of plugins that when I try to do "Find Unused Dependencies" on "org.osate.aadl2.modelsupport" with 1024M allocated to Eclipse's java heap space, I get an out of memory error after about 10 minutes of processing, most of it at 96% complete with "3 unused dependencies found".

I can throw more resources as the problem (I'm currently running a test with 2048M allocated to Eclipse's heap space), but I want to know - what are the practical limits of this feature? With 2048M heap space, it has been running longer but just keeps eating up more RAM.

[image: JVisualVM Looking at Eclipse during "Find Unused Dependencies"]

Why does it take 10+ minutes to run and use a huge amount of heap space? Is there a memory leak, or do I have incorrect assumptions about how it works?

Update: [I opened an Eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=512464).

Comment: I work on a project with 144 plug-ins; Find Unused Dependencies finished in about 2-3 seconds for every plugin.xml I checked so far.

Comment: @AdamHorvath This turned out to be an eclipse bug. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=512464